# Two WWW in dotcloud.yml

Tags: dotcloud

Is it possible to put two 'www' entries into the *dotcloud.yml* file? I want to have a type:node and a type:static, but of which are in the 'www' section of the *.yml* file. Not sure if I can do that or not, but I sure would love to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Service names need to be unique, so you won't be able to have both a `node` and `static` service named 'www'.

Is there a reason why you want them both to have a name of 'www'?

Service names can be anything you want and are only used to identify the service, and have nothing to do with the domain names you want associated with the service. So it is usually best to name them something obvious so that it is easier to know what each service is doing.

Here is an example of what you could do for your `dotcloud.yml`

```
www:                   # Could actually be anything: front, joe...
    type: node         # But this must be a valid service type.
static:                  # There again, the name can be anything you like.
    type: static       # ...but the type has to be a valid one.
```

For more information about the `dotcloud.yml` file check out. http://docs.dotcloud.com/guides/build-file/

Comment: Fetching @Ken Cochrane... perfect answer. You answered all of my questions. Thank you!